# web2py: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when it shouldn't

Tags: database, web2py, data-access-layer

I have this table:

```
db.define_table('block',
    Field('ore_id', 'reference ore'),
    Field('location', type='integer', required=True, notnull = True),
    Field('x', type='integer'),
    Field('y', type='integer'),
    Field('block_mass_tn', type='double')
)
```

and this:

```
db.define_table('block_processing_line_1',
    Field('block_location', 'reference block'),
    Field('processing_time_d', type='double'),
    Field('concentrate_tn', type='double'),
    Field('concentrate_quality', type='double')
)
```

In the table `block` I have 100 entries, `id` and `location` running from 1-100. When I add a new record to the latter table with `block_location` being 1, it accepts it, but when I try to add 2 or 3 or so on, it won't accept it and it says "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed". I have other tables, which have that identical field: `Field('block_location', 'reference block'),` but they don't have any problem with values above 1. What is wrong here?

One other thing that comes in mind is that I had the same problem before with that table and I realized I had made a typo: `Field('block_location', 'reference ore'),` so I referenced a wrong table and that table `ore` only had one entry (thus accepting only 1 and nothing else). But now even though I fixed it, the problem persists. Could there be some traces of that former line somewhere in the DAL? I truncated both tables (`block` and `block_processing_line_1`after fixing.

Comment: Have you compiled the app or turned off migrations? If neither, maybe try dropping the `block_processing_line_1` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anthony:

> Have you compiled the app or turned off migrations? If neither, maybe
>   try dropping the block_processing_line_1 table.

This solved it! I dropped the table and saved, "undropped" the table and saved, and after that it worked as it should. So this line:

```
db.block_processing_line_1.drop()
```